# Very basic - Java array as class variable

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Foo{
     int[] doop;

     public Foo(){
          this.doop={1,2,3,4,5};
     }
}
```

I can't compile this, Java ME SDK gives me a bunch of "Illegal Start of Expression" errors. Why? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.doop= new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this in constructor, because this syntax is allowed only for declaration with initialization. Fix to this:

```
class Foo{
     int[] doop = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};

     public Foo(){

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo{
     int[] doop;

     public Foo(){
          this.doop= new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
     }
}
```